# spring batch does not stop, inner jobs keep runnig

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have nested jobs, main jobs calls many child job and they again call other child jobs. I am using spring batch remote partitioning to partition step execution.

If I stop main job using spring batch admin, it doesn't stop job. All jobs keep running.

It should stop all inner jobs and on restart should start inner jobs from the same place where they were stopped.

Is that because of nested jobs ? Is there limitation of nesting level ? or is that because of remote partitioning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to stop a child job from a parent job isn't currently supported in Spring Batch.  The way you'd have to do it is to actually stop the child, then the parent.  That being said, it doesn't seem like an unreasonable enhancement and pull requests are always welcome (take a look in the `org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobStep` of where updates would need to occur).

Comment: can flows be nested ? will there be a same problem if flows are nested? As a work around to above use case, instead of calling child jobs from parent, if I use flows and call flows in main jobs and  individual small jobs ?